# About submitting a paper in algebra?

Tags: modules

My questions are about submitting  papers related to modules category:
(1) how much does it take (usually) to get the acceptance from a journal with good impact factor?
(2) which journals(with good impact factor) take less time?
(3) can I submit my paper in two different journals at the same time, since I'm not sure which one would accept it? Or it has to be one and wait for their response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @optimalcontrol: That is completely incorrect. The purpose of Meta is to discuss this website and how things are run here.

Comment: Ok I will try to put my question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The paper needs to be good, and one of the following must hold:
(a) the paper is AMAZING, or (b) you are well-established in the field, or (c) you get lucky.

(2) It is difficult to find out journal backlogs, but some places to publish lists periodically.

(3) No.  Journals usually say in their application materials that by submitting it to them you are certifying that this material is not published or submitted elsewhere.